# scale in includegraphics not works

Tags: graphics

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
)
Runaway argument?
 Extension-1, SH Hall\\ \end {tabular} \end {center} \vspace *{\fill \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \Gin@iii.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> delete.tex

?
```

Without `scale` code runs well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome,caption}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \begin{figure}
     \includegraphics{example-image-a} % this runs well
  %  \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a} % this not run
    \caption{Taken from Internet(black and white image)}
  \end{figure}
  {\Huge\textbf{To Buy}}
\\
  \LARGE
\vspace{2cm}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \faPhone{} \textbf{01515-611989}\\
    \faHome{} Room - \textbf{1406}, Extension-1, SH Hall\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You need the graphicx package with x at the end.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. Should I delete the question?